# Function not retrieving values from an array correctly

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4

I have a function called `Crossed1` that I'm trying to implement to collect values into an array.
Then from that array I want to find the highest value of the last 5 bars.

```
int Crossed1()
  {

   static int CurrentDirection1=0;
   static int LastDirection1=0;
   static bool FirstTime1=true;
   
//----
   if((BB20DO<BB30DO)&& (CandleCLOSE<BB20DO) && (CandleCLOSEp<BB20DOp)  && (RSIi< 30))
      CurrentDirection1=1;  // line1 above line2
   if(BB20DO>BB30DO)
      CurrentDirection1=2;  // line1 below line2
//----
   if(FirstTime1==true) // Need to check if this is the first time the function is run
     {
      FirstTime1=false; // Change variable to false
      LastDirection1=CurrentDirection1; // Set new direction
      return (0);
     }

   if(CurrentDirection1!=LastDirection1 && FirstTime1==false) // If not the first time and there is a direction change
     {
      LastDirection1=CurrentDirection1; // Set new direction
      return(CurrentDirection1); // 1 for up, 2 for down
     }
   else
     {
      return(0);  // No direction change
           
     }
         
  }
```

Arraymax to retrieve the max value

```
int ArrayCalcMax()
   {   
      int bars = 5;
      int malookback=bars;
     
                  
      double madaily[5];
      double dllv;
      
      for(int i = 0; i < malookback; i++)
      madaily[i] = Crossed1();
      Print(" array[",i,"] = ",madaily[i]);

      int maxPos = ArrayMaximum(madaily,malookback,0); // Check the "maxPos" to make sure it is in range as it could be "-1" if it fails
      Print(" maxPos = ", maxPos );

      if( maxPos >= 0 )
         {
         dllv = madaily[maxPos];  // Please note that "dllv" is a local variable that will be discarded as soon as you return
         Print(" dllv = ", dllv );
         }
   else
      Print("Something is wrong!");

      
   return(dllv);
}
```

I think as the code is currently, I'm only collecting the current value in the array, is that correct?

If i try to include the `i`, it returns the error `Wrong parameters count`

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These lines:

```
for(int i = 0; i < malookback; i++)
      madaily[i] = Crossed1();
      Print(" array[",i,"] = ",madaily[i]);
```

don't do what you think they do.

They translate to

```
for(int i = 0; i< malookback; i++)
{
    madaily[i] = Crossed1();
}
Print(" array[",i,"] = ",madaily[i]); // Error because i has been destructed
```

When writing loop statements in C++, you have to include curly braces `{}` around its contents if it contains more than one line of code.

Change those lines to

```
for(int i = 0; i < malookback; i++)
{
    madaily[i] = Crossed1();
    Print(" array[",i,"] = ",madaily[i]);
}
```

and it will work as intended.

Comment: Any thoughts in how can i solve the array issue?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you JensB.

as you said it worked OK.
nonetheless the value doesn't store in the next calculation:

```
    17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[0] = 1
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[1] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[2] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[3] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[4] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  maxPos = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:20:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  dllv = 1
```

the result for the array [1] should be 1 and it appears the value zero.

```
17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[0] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[1] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[2] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[3] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  array[4] = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  maxPos = 0
0   17:10:44.622    2019.08.23 12:40:00  BBReverse V1 EURUSD,H4:  dllv = 0
```

Thanks
André